# R's `randomForest` predicts constant value (but correctly differentiates OOB)

Tags: r, random-forest

I created a simple `data.frame` called `dataset` with 200 rows and two columns `predictor` and `outcome`:

- The first 100 rows contain `predictor="a"` and `outcome=1`.
- The next 100 rows contain `predictor="b"` and `outcome=2`.

I then fit a regression `randomForest` on this data. The OOB predictions are correct (`1` for the first 100 rows, `2` for the others). But when I call `predict`, then I get constant predictions of `1`, whether I feed `"a"` or `"b"` in!

What am I doing wrong?

I am running R 4.1.2 and `randomForest_4.6-14`. R code below:

```
library(randomForest)
n_per_class <- 100

dataset <- data.frame(
    outcome=c(rep(1,n_per_class),rep(2,n_per_class)),
    predictor=c(rep("a",n_per_class),rep("b",n_per_class)))

model <- randomForest(outcome~predictor,data=dataset)

by(predict(model),dataset$predictor,mean)   # yields 1 and 2

predict(model,newdata=data.frame(predictor="a"))    # yields 1
predict(model,newdata=data.frame(predictor="b"))    # yields 1, too!
```

Incidentally, the same happens if I use 1,000 or 10,000 data points for each class, or if I replace the constant values 1 and 2 by uniformly distributed random variables in $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$, respectively.

Comment: [Difference between factor and character variables running randomForest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827087/difference-between-factor-and-character-variables-running-randomforest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's related to passing only 1 row in newdata, as

`predict(model,newdata=data.frame(predictor=c("b","a")))`

works fine.

However, my guess is that the real issue is in your `predictor` variable, in that you didn't code it as a factor. If you do that then

```
predict(model,data.frame(predictor=factor("a",levels=c("a","b"))))
predict(model,data.frame(predictor=factor("b",levels=c("a","b"))))
```

predicts right.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. This is a little strange, but good to know. (Incidentally, for the benefit of later visitors: of course we also need to code the original `predictor` as a `factor`.)